How to resize a video with FFMPEG so that it has a max size, horizontal or vertical, without losing aspect ratio?
There are lots of questions on SO about resizing video but they all seem to assume orientation. Let's say that I am ingesting user videos and sometimes they are horizontal and sometimes vertical. I'd like to downscale them to at most 1920x1080 or 1080x1920, depending on orientation, but never upscale. I can't examine videos ahead of time so I am looking for a filter command that will do all this logic in one go. Anyone have anything like this handy?

This command would check the videos orientation and would scale it accordingly.
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale='if(gte(iw,ih),min(1920,iw),-2)':'if(gte(iw,ih),-2,min(1080,ih))'" -c:a copy output.mp4

